# Java string results different to C#

Tags: java, c#, datainputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm reading a socket stream and converting the byte array to a single string in both Java & C#, but the results are different...

C# code:

```
string text = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Java code:

```
String text = new String(data);
```

One of the potential issues I encountered upon research was that C#'s default encoding was `UTF-32` & Java's was `UTF8`, as well as C# uses little endian and Java uses Big endian, so the solution would be to define charset in java as `UTF-32LE` but even then it returns entirely different to C# and most if not all of the string is a combination of `�`

Just as extra information regarding my methods in Java I'm using `ByteArrayOutputStream` to store data from `DataInputStream` & in C# I'm using `MemoryStream` to store data from `NetworkStream`

Comment: Java's default encoding is whatever your platform supports by default.  It's intended for students who want a "simple" way to be compatible with a local platform.  If you want UTF-8, you have to specify it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: Are you sure `Encoding.Default` is UTF-32?  That seems like a strange default, since no Windows system uses that normally.  Perhaps you should print out `Encoding.Default`, and/or examine the actual bytes in `data` on the Java side?

Answer (score 2):

As the bytes in the stream were encoded using some encoding, you must explicitly set the correct encoding in your C# and Java code.

They use different default encodings.

To make the byte stream interoperable, you must stick with one encoding which is used to encode string to bytes. Or exchange the encoding type somewhere in the stream.

Comment: I'm trying to configure Java to output the same results as C#, someone stated that `UTF-32` was C#'s default and it uses Little Endian, so I tried `new String(bytes, "UTF-32LE")` but it still outputs entirely different results to C#

Comment: How different? Just little endian and big endian different or is nothing comparable?

Comment: @Michael If I use `UTF8` in Java it's similar to some extent but entire string doesn't match & leaves some response unreadable with sequences of `�`, if I use the suggested `UTF-32LE` it's non comparable, entire string is `�` and some other variations such as `䀀Ā ` but nothing readable.

Comment: Try looking at the byte array and compare that. Not sure it this is the problem but do you know what the difference is between big endian and little endian?

Comment: @Michael I'm not familiar with Big endian & Little endian, but it isn't in the way the bytes are stored? Big endian/Little endian is almost a reverse of one another.

Comment: Do you know how the source stream is encoded?  That's the key - figure it out and the problem is solved (just read the stream using the same encoding).  If you don't know how the stream is encoded, write a simple test program that reads a sample string (into a `byte[]`) and allows you to decode that byte array in a variety of encodings (with and without a BOM).  The find the one that's the best

Comment: If you're seeing minor differences in UTF8, then the problem may be the fonts you're using to look at the text. Make sure that you view the output the exact same way (like, save it both to a file and use the same editor, or use the same terminal/command prompt to run both programs)